# Android widget to turn on/off Wi-Fi, mobile data, BT, etc. (and more if possible)

Tags: android, widget

I'm looking for a widget for Android 12 that allows the user to easily toggle on/off various things from the home screen: Wi-Fi, mobile data, Bluetooth, etc.

The more customizable the widget, the better.

Free and open-source would be nice, but it's not a hard requirement.

I remember that there was an app on older Android versions called "Power Toggles" or something, and that it worked very well.  Unfortunately can't find it anymore.

Comment: Which version(s) of Android?  IIRC, Google unfortunately made it impossible for the user to toggle mobile data via a widget starting around Android 5 (very approximately).  Lacking UX consistency within Android, a widget could toggle Wi-Fi the last time I checked, even though it couldn't toggle mobile data. I don't know if toggling Wi-Fi is still possible with the latest version of Android, of if Google took away that too.  I never tried it for BT.

Comment: Android 12. I edited the post.

Comment: Thanks for your edit.  If you have a preference for recommendations for gratis (free of financial cost) or paid applications, that will be another good addition to your question.  BTW, I remember that "Power Toggles" app, or whatever it was called, too!  It was so good, it was typically the first app I would install.

Comment: What's wrong with the QuickSettings toggles you can expand to from the notification bar? Don't they include all that anymore with Android 12? They're the reason why many of those widgets where no longer developed (PowerToggle is gone, too). You can find some of those left [in my app listing here](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_switches).

Comment: @Izzy Not all; mobile data, for instance, is not included anymore.  That's a neat page you have, you should add the content as an answer.

Comment: Thanks! But adding that page as an answer would be a "list answer". We like rather precise answers here describing how a recommended software meets the requirements, what makes it recommendable, etc ;) As for mobile data: I still have that toggle there on my Android-11 device. But maybe that's because it's running a custom ROM (LineageOS).

Comment: FYI, I've tried Notification Toggle and it does not work with Android 12.  It gets installed but toggles behave erratically.